# Is there a non-independent country with “full fiscal autonomy”?

Tags: local-autonomy

In the post-election debate in the United Kingdom, where the [Scottish National Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_National_Party) [won 56 out of 59 Scottish Westminster seats and 50% of the Scottish popular vote](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/election/2015/results/scotland), one point of discussion is how much to increase devolution of powers from the UK to the Scottish government.  Reports say that Scottish First Minister Nicola Sturgeon asks for [full fiscal autonomy](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-scotland-scotland-politics-32746049).

Is there any existing location where a constituent country, federal state, or other non-independent country, has full fiscal autonomy?

Comment: I believe the Swiss cantons are candidates, but I'm not sure exactly how fully they are autonomous. Economically strong cantons have to give money to economically weak cantons (which is in itself a hot debate here, some people wish to remove this system).

Comment: Check Navarra and Euskadi, un Spain.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by fiscal autonomy? From what I understand, the proposals on the table for Scotland grant Scotland the right to govern its domestic fiscal affairs, but would not allow it to, for example, not pay taxes for the national Army. In that way, the UK is just a federal system.

Comment: I'm not sure if Hong Kong and Macau count.

Comment: @Bregalad The Swiss system seems (in that respect) like a run-of-the-mill federal system with the different levels of government able to raise taxes as they see fit. There is a direct federal income tax and the new VAT is also flowing to the federal budget so the cantons do not have any special autonomy compared to US states, German or Austrian provinces, etc. Of course, that would be new for the UK (or other unitary states like France, the Netherlands, etc.) where most taxes are raised nationally even when the money goes back to the lower levels of governments.

Comment: Under EU law, there's no _full_ fiscal autonomy for member states - VAT is a shared responsibility. Of course post-Brexit this stops, so Scotland might then gain fiscal autonomy.

Comment: @MSalters Source?  Different EU countries have different levels of VAT, and AFAIK EU does not directly receive any proceedings from that.

Comment: @gerrit: The EU enforces a VAT system, with two rates, and determines which goods fall in which rate category. The EU sets minimum and maximum rates. As for receiving direct proceeds, the EU receives 0.3% percent point of the VAT revenues. (Source: Council Directive 2006/112/EC of 28 November 2006 "on the common system of value added tax")

Comment: @Masclins what about them? while they are 'autonomous communities', they do not have 'full fiscal autonomy'

Answer (score 2):

The example is in the UK itself. Most of the [British overseas territories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Overseas_Territories) have full fiscal autonomy.

However there is a problem. Most of those territories exploited their position to become tax havens, that is acceptable when the population is small and the beneficiaries will be only a small elite. Scotland has a population of more than 5 million people, it does not fit in the model, so probably the request for full fiscal autonomy will be left pending indefinitely.